# Why the number of vertices of the exported obj model is three will become more

Tags: javascript, three.js, vertices, objloader

When I tried to export a plane obj model in blender, I found it in three JS, the number of vertices has increased,

obj model
[Blender Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hq5GA.png)

renderer [After Renderer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7luwQ.png)

Comment: Hi, have you tried to post your answer on https://blender.stackexchange.com/?
They specifically process Blender-related questions.

Answer (score 0):

The stray triangles make me think that, rather than additional vertices, what you're seeing is that one or more n-gons in your mesh (faces that have more than three sides) are being triangulated incorrectly somewhere in Blender's exporter or Three's importer.

[image: OP's renderer screenshot, with additional triangles highlighted]

Blender can handle n-gons (faces that have more than three sides), but a real-time renderer like Three.js thinks in triangles; if you try to give it n-gons instead of triangles, either the exporter or the importer will try to triangulate them by itself, with sometimes unfortunate results.

There are multiple ways to manually triangulate a mesh; here is just one.

In Blender, select your object and press <kbd>Tab ⭾</kbd> to enter Edit Mode.  Press <kbd>3</kbd> to enter Face Selection Mode, then <kbd>A</kbd> to select all faces, then <kbd>F</kbd> (*Vertex* » *New Edge/Face from Vertices*) to merge them into a single face.  This may not be strictly necessary depending on particulars of your mesh that are unknown to me, but it gets us to a known state for the next step.

Now your mesh will have one face, and it will be selected.  Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> (*Face* » *Triangulate Faces*), and that single face will be split into several triangles, which will look something like the following.

[image: Blender screenshot showing triangulation]

The exact arrangement of the triangles may be different on your own model; what's important, though, is that all of the faces on the model are now triangles.

If you export the model from Blender and import it in Three.js now, it should appear as expected.